# FlowDocument Parsing Error with <ed:Arc> in the document body

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I have the following code for reading a `FlowDocument` into memory but whenever I try to parse it I get `XamlParseException` with the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing}Arc'.' Line number '6' and line position '5'.
```

Here is what my `FD.xaml` file contains:

**FD.xaml**

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia" 
              xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" >
    <Paragraph>
        <Canvas Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="402">
            <ed:Arc ArcThickness="10" Fill="Black" EndAngle="360" Height="7" Width="11" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <ed:Arc ArcThickness="10" Fill="Black" EndAngle="360" Height="7" Width="11" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
            <ed:Arc ArcThickness="10" Fill="Black" EndAngle="360" Height="7" Width="11" Margin="0,24,0,0"/>         
            <ed:Arc ArcThickness="10" Fill="Black" EndAngle="360" Height="7" Width="11" Margin="368,108,0,0"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
...
String xamlContent = ReadFileContents("FD.xaml");
FlowDocument doc = XamlReader.Parse(xamlContent) as FlowDocument; // Error occurs right here
...
```

**What I tried so far:**
Added reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: For me the reference to "Microsoft.Expression.Drawing" fixed all compilation problems (VS2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
```

with:

```
xmlns:ed="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Shapes;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Drawing"
```